# MVC Validations not firing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2. My form validations are not firing. I can not figure out whats wrong here.

**Model:**

```
 public class Stock
    {
        public int StockID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select a Client")]
        public int ClientID { get; set; }

         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select An Item")]
        public int ItemID { get; set; }


           [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Item Count")]
          public int ItemCount { get; set; }

           [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Item Price")]
        public double Price { get; set; }

           [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Other Expences")]
        public double OtherExpences { get; set; }

        public double TotalStockValue { get; set; }

          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Delivery date")]
        public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Client> lstClient { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Item> lstItem { get; set; }

        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {

                try
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        StockRepository rep = new StockRepository();
                        Stock stock = new Stock();
                        stock.ClientID =Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ClientID"]);
                        stock.DeliveryDate =Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["DeliveryDate"]);
                        stock.Description = Request.Form["Description"];
                        stock.ItemCount =Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ItemCount"]);
                        stock.ItemID =Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ItemID"]);
                        stock.Price =Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["Price"]);
                        stock.OtherExpences = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["OtherExpences"]);
                        stock.TotalStockValue =Convert.ToDouble((stock.Price * stock.ItemCount)+stock.OtherExpences);
                        rep.Create(stock);
                        rep.Save();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                        return View();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }

        }
```

**View:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/StockMasterPage.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<StockManagement.Models.Stock>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Create
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css") %>" />
  <script src="<%= Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js") %>"></script>
  <script src="<%= Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js") %>"></script>

  <script>
      $(function () {
          $("#DeliveryDate").datepicker();
      });
  </script>

    <h2>Create</h2>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>
              <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.Label("Select Client")%>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ClientID, new SelectList(Model.lstClient, "ClientID", "Name"), "-- Please Select a Client --") %>
                 <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientID)%>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.Label("Select Item") %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
               <%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ItemID, new SelectList(Model.lstItem, "ItemID", "ItemName"), "-- Please Select an Item --")%>
                 <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemID)%>
            </div>


            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemCount) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ItemCount) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemCount) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherExpences) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OtherExpences) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherExpences) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeliveryDate) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DeliveryDate) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeliveryDate) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description) %>
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the server side validations working.
Add a call to UpdateModel or TryUpdateModel which will populate your model and fire the validation rules setting the ModelState.IsValid property correctly.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {

                try
                {
                    Stock stock = new Stock();
                    TryUpdateModel(stock);

                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        StockRepository rep = new StockRepository();

                        stock.ClientID =Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ClientID"]);
                        stock.DeliveryDate =Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["DeliveryDate"]);
                        stock.Description = Request.Form["Description"];
                        stock.ItemCount =Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ItemCount"]);
                        stock.ItemID =Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ItemID"]);
                        stock.Price =Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["Price"]);
                        stock.OtherExpences = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["OtherExpences"]);
                        stock.TotalStockValue =Convert.ToDouble((stock.Price * stock.ItemCount)+stock.OtherExpences);
                        rep.Create(stock);
                        rep.Save();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                        return View();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }

        }
```

The built in server side validation for MVC 2 will only work if your action accepts the a Model object as a parameter. This causes MVC to create the model object and automatically map the incoming form input values to it.  As part of this process, it will also check to see whether the DataAnnotation validation attributes for the model are valid.  If everything is valid, then the ModelState.IsValid check within our code will return true.

When your action accepts a FormCollection this does not happen therefore, the DataAnnotation validation attributes are never evaluated and the ModelState.IsValid is never set.  We can correct this issue by simply performing  those steps ourselves.  MVC 2 provides functions that we can use to do this (UpdateModel and TryUpdateModel).  The difference is Update will throw if there is a validation error whereas TryUpdate will simply set the IsValid to false.

An added benefit of using the UpdateModel is that an empty model will be populated with all the values from the form collection for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have set **ClientValidationEnabled** as **true** in web config or add  following code before using BeginForm

```
 <% Html.ClientValidationEnabled = true; %>
```

Comment: gets an error "does not contain a definition for ClientValidationEnabled"

Comment: it means you have not included the MicrosoftMvcJqueryValidation in your project. please refer to best possible secenario on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/10/03/client-side-validation-for-mvc-2-p2.aspx